# align div inside a div that contain image inside

Tags: html, css

I set margin 0 auto so why it dosen't work?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g53a3/

```
.main_logo {
    float: left;
    width: 157px;
    height: 123px;
    border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
}
.app-thumb-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 124px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Check this with text-align: center; http://jsfiddle.net/g53a3/6/

Answer (score 2):

Make the image as `display:block;` or wrap the image with another div and add image classs to that div.

```
.app-thumb-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 124px;
    height: 97px;
    display:block;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g53a3/1/)**

Comment: @sowmya but it still not in the hrizontal center

Comment: @user3128813 Really??? R u sure u are asking about horizontal or vertical align.. coz in my demo it is horizontally aligned to center..

Answer (score 2):

For horizontal center: Display `image` as `block` element, like :

```
display:block;
```

For both horizontal and vertical center: you can use `position: absolute` - it is one of many ways to center it:

add to parent:

```
position: relative;
```

and for a child:

```
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g53a3/7/

Comment: Code and example would have been nice.

Comment: @andy  but it still not in the hrizontal center

Comment: It IS horizontal center

Comment: @user3128813 Check updated answer for both horizontal and vertical center.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Apply display: block; to image and then margin: 0 auto; will do the trick (solution for block elements)
2. Apply text-align: center; to images's parent div and you are ok too (solution for inline elements)

both work great, but image is an inline element by default so probably the second solution is the most common.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` to make it absolute center

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/g53a3/4/)**

**CSS**

```
.main_logo {
    float: left;
    width: 157px;
    height: 123px;
    border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    position:relative;
}
.app-thumb-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 124px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For margin specify 13px instead of 0 and add display:block property, see below

```
 .app-thumb-image {
            margin:13px auto;
            width: 124px;
            height: 97px;
            display:block;
            background-color: #000;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g53a3/5/

Here is how I got 13px -- (main_logo height - app-thumb-image height)/2 ie (123-97)/2=13